# Magento 2.4.6 dont show images from wysiwyg folder

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have a problem with magento 2.4.6 wysiwyg folder images.

Yesterday everything works fine, today at morning i see that images for banners dont show, product images show correctly.

I try to run:  bin/magento media-gallery:sync and bin/magento media-content:sync.

I didnt work anything on server or magento configuration.

Please help

[image: frontend]

[image: backend]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to allow `.renditions` directory in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Magento 2 folder permission.**

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;

sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try his once**

Replace “`Option FollowSymLinks`” with “`Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`” in `pub/media/.htaccess` file and `pub/.htaccess` file